# Facebook method for getting max image size?

Tags: facebook

When an image is uploaded to Facebook, it caps the image's resolution to a max of 2048 pixels in the bigger dimension and proportional in the smaller dimension. However, there is no guarantee that this behavior will not change in the near future.
My question is: Is there an Facebook API Method for retrieving the max size for an uploading image?
I know that Facebook will reduce the image size once it gets to its server, but it is important to reduce the image before uploading, because the upload is being made from a mobile environment, and I do not want to waste bandwidth for uploading an image that will get capped, because it means a waste of battery life and data traffic.
I could diminish the image to this dimension of 2048 pixels, but there are no guarantees that Facebook will not raise the max accepted size to 4096 in the near future.
So, is there a reliable way? Thank you!

Comment: Nope, there is no API endpoint for getting that kind of info. You could upload a “big” image yourself regularly, and see to what max size it get’s cropped though … could even be a very small image (file-size wise). And then you could delete it afterwards again. If this approach is a sensible one under real conditions … up to you :-)

Comment: It could be an option in certain situations, but not in most cases, doing so would use the data traffic that i am trying to save...

Comment: You don’t have to do it from your mobile … you could set it up as a cronjob on a web server, do it maybe once a day … and then offer your own “API Endpoint” in form of a URL where your mobile app can ask for the current maximum image dimensions …